# How can I emulate a DB link locally?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a local dev copy of our production DB. However, in production, we have a DB link to a second DB, and this is not available outside of a production environment.

I'm pretty new when it comes to this kind of stuff. Would it be possible to create a second local DB to point my DB link to in Oracle SQL Developer? Or could I create a new user on my existing DB and point the DB link to that user's schema? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: A DB link can point to the same database, which isn't usually useful or necessary (and even the same user, though that's even less useful); so just create a new user and creating a link to that should work. But how is the link accessed - do you have code that references something against a specific link name, or through a synonym to a linked table, or something else? Just wondering if you actually need a link at all - depends how you use it.

Comment: The reason I suggested a DB link pointing to the same DB is it doesn't really matter where it resides. I have a query in Java that references both databases (the DB link is references through a specific link name) and I want to test it end to end with some manufactured data.

Comment: The more flexible way is to use synonyms for all the interface objects. It doesn't matter what resides behind them: table, view, pipelined function or remote source. With them you may just replace base object to local one (which is also allows you to reconfigure distributed setup).

Comment: _"The more flexible way is to use synonyms for all the interface objects. "_   No doubt, and good to know for future reference.  But in the OP's case, that would involve reworking an unknown amount of production code.